# Jquery website not open up in android browser?

Tags: jquery, android, jquery-mobile

I try to open up some jquery web site , But it shows an error " Data Connectivity problem " in android browser. For example: http://jquerymobile.com/blog/2011/11/16/announcing-jquery-mobile-1-0/  but this site not open up in android browser.

Actually i try to create on mobile web site using JQuery, every thing works fine in IOS, but the CSS and some other stuff regarding jquery is not supported in android browser.

If any one know the solutions , please help me out.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You need to set `webView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);`
Also, add **internet permissions** in your manifest file.

Comment: For your kind information,i have a problem in default browser of android not in webview of my application.

Comment: I am opening above url in default browser using: Intent browserIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse("http://jquerymobile.com/blog/2011/11/16/announcing-jquery-mobile-1-0/"));
    startActivity(browserIntent);  It is working fine for me.